# Elasticsearch Authentication/SSL Plugin for the v5 Alpha

Tags: authentication, ssl, elasticsearch

Are there any free authentication and SSL plugins for the v5 Alpha of Elasticsearch other than X-Pack? Only thing I've really come across is setting up a nginx proxy. Most of the other plugins I've found have not been updated to the v5 alpha yet.